# Kolosov-Muskhelisvili formulae and stress derivation

Tags: complex-analysis

May I ask you how to derive the following formula. It is based on the Kolosov-Mushkelisvili formulae in mechanics, but I could not get what is written in this book i.e. Savin, G. N. (1968). Stress Distribution around Holes.

The Kolosov-Muskhelisvili formulae is,

$\sigma_{r}+\sigma_{\theta} = 2[\Phi(\zeta)+\overline{\Phi(\zeta)}]$

$\sigma_\theta-\sigma_{r}+2i\tau_{\rho\theta}=\dfrac{2\zeta}{\rho^2\overline{\omega'(\zeta)}}[\overline{\omega(\zeta)}\Phi'(\zeta)+\omega'(\zeta)\Psi(\zeta)]$

where $\Phi(\zeta)$ and $\Psi(\zeta)$ are defined as:

$\Phi(\zeta)=\dfrac{\phi'(\zeta)}{\omega'(\zeta)}$

$\Psi(\zeta)=\dfrac{\psi'(\zeta)}{\omega'(\zeta)}$

in which the prime symbol is for derivative and the overline is the complex conjugate.

For a circle, the two functions can be defined as:

$\phi(\zeta)=\dfrac{pR}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{\zeta}+2\zeta\right)$

$\psi(\zeta)=-\dfrac{pR}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{\zeta}+\zeta-\zeta^3 \right)$

and $\zeta^k = (\rho e^{i\theta})^k = \rho^k(\cos k\theta + i\sin k\theta$)

And,

$\omega(\zeta)=\dfrac{R}{\zeta}$

$R=1$ is the radius of the circle.

Using all of the definition mentioned above, the $\sigma_\theta$ can be obtained from the Kolosov-Muskhelisvili formulae by inserting the corresponding value from all of the above definitions,

$$\sigma_\theta=\dfrac{p}{2}\left[(1+\rho^2)-(1+3\rho^4)\cos 2\theta\right]$$

$$\sigma_r=\dfrac{p}{2}\left[(1-\rho^2)+(1-4\rho^4+3\rho^4)\cos 2\theta\right]$$

$$\sigma_{r\theta}=\dfrac{p}{2}(1+2\rho^2-3\rho^4)\sin 2\theta$$

My question is, how do we arrive that definition of $\sigma_\theta$? Yes, I am only interested in $\sigma_\theta$. I am not able to get it from the Kolosov-Muskhelisvili formulae. I have done it using substitution and elimination, still cannot it exactly as what is written in the book.

Can anyone help me to prove it?

Comment: I doubt that "$\zeta$ is arbitrary points in the plane of complex variables" is sufficient. If it's inside the unit circle - you have one result, if outside - another.

Comment: Since you do not state the range of $k$, why don't you just replace $k$ by $1-k$? And check the result you cite: you cited it incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I have tried that. Replacing $k$ by $1-k$ gives me a wrong answer. And what do you mean by "cited it incorrectly"?

Comment: I repeat that you stated the "Savin result" incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I have corrected it. Is that what you mean? Are you able to give an answer with the "correct" citation from Savin (1968)

Comment: I gave you the answer, without any citations.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko thanks so much for the answer. I appreciate it... It will be sometimes for me to understand your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78255/discussion-between-beetiau-and-alexandre-eremenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a$ is an integer, $a>0$. Let
$$I(a)=\int_\gamma t^{-a}\frac{t+\zeta}{t-\zeta}\frac{dt}{t}=2\pi i(\mbox{sum of the residues}),$$
where residues are taken at the poles in the unit disk. The function has two poles,
one at $0$ another at $\zeta$. The pole at $\zeta$ is simple and the residue
at this pole is $2\zeta^{-a}$. Sum of all residues, including the one
at $\infty$ is always $0$.

When $|\zeta|<1$, both poles are in the unit disk, and the sum of their residues
is $0$ because the residue at $\infty$ is zero. If $|\zeta|>1$, there is only one pole in the unit disk and the residue at $0$ is negative of the residue at $\zeta$, so it is $-2\zeta^{-a}$.

The case $a\leq 0$ is easier because there is only one pole at $\zeta$.

Then put $a=k$ or $a=1-k$, or whatever you want.

Comment: It means that replacing $k$ with $1-k$ should be correct, isn't it?

Comment: If you know the answer FOR EVERY k, then you can replace it by whatever you want.